# Scheme based on functional dependencies

Tags: sql, dependencies, functional-dependencies, transitive-dependency

I've been trying to figure this out in my head but i'm really stuck and would appreciate some help. Given the scheme

```
R(a,b,c,d)
fd1: a->c
fd2: b->d
```

Would it be accurate to say that the key here would be {a,b} ? If that's true, then would it also be accurate to say that attributes c,d due to their partial dependence on either a or b need to be in their own tables? Resulting in a scheme of the following manner?

```
R(a,b)
r1(a,c)
r2(b,d)
```

Or would it be right simply to have

```
R(a,c)
r1(b,d)
```

Surely a,b have to be present in some sort of form, as they're the key right? I'm not 100% sure. Help understanding this would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{a,b} is the only key for R. R is in 1NF.

In order to reach at least 2NF, remove partial key dependencies by projection.

- r<sub>1</sub>{ **a** c}
- r<sub>2</sub>{ **b** d}

This is the minimum cover. Both r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub> are in 6NF. The key to R doesn't need to exist, because R doesn't exist. But R can be recovered from the Cartesian product of r<sub>1</sub> and r<sub>2</sub>.

Using SQL . . .

```
create table t1 (
  a integer not null,
  b integer not null,
  c integer not null,
  d integer not null,
  primary key (a, b)
);

insert into t1 values
(1, 1, 10, 100),
(1, 2, 10, 200),
(2, 1, 20, 100),
(2, 2, 20, 200);
```

Note that this preserves the FDs a->c and b->d.

```
create table t2 (
  a integer primary key,
  c integer not null
);

insert into t2
select distinct a, c from t1;

create table t3 (
  b integer primary key,
  d integer not null
);

insert into t3 
select distinct b, d from t1;

drop table t1;
```

Now we can look at the data in tables t2 and t3.

```
select * from t2;
a   c
--
1   10
2   20

select * from t3;
b   d
--
1   100
2   200
```

And we can recover t1 through the Cartesian product of t2 and t3.

```
select t2.a, t3.b, t2.c, t3.d
from t2, t3;
a  b   c  d
--
1  1  10  100
1  2  10  200
2  1  20  100
2  2  20  200
```